# Determinant of symmetric matrix of the form $v\otimes v$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Note that for $V=\mathbf{R}^n$,
$$S^2V = \{ v\otimes w \mid v, w\in V\text{ and }v\otimes w=w\otimes v \} =\{ A\in \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbf{R}) \mid A=A^T \}.$$
Clearly, $S^2V $ contains $O=\{ v\otimes v \mid v\in V\}$.

I want to insist that $\{ A\in S^2V \mid \det A = 0\} = O$ .

Can this statement can be found in some reference? Or this is statement wrong?

In my thought, the $n=2, 3$ cases hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the introductory part of the question.  Although $S^2V$ can be regarded as the space $\{A:A=A^T\}$ of symmetric matrices, the set of $v\otimes w$ with $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$ is a smaller set.  It generates $S^2V$ as a vector space, but it is not equal to that vector space (unless the dimension of $V$ is very small).

Now for your actual question, notice that a symmetric matrix of the form $v\otimes v$ would have rank 1.  But the $3\times 3$ matrix $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}$ has rank 2 and its determinant is zero, so it is a counterexample to your conjecture.